# Tkinter: how to keep frame visible when shrink main window

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, frame

I'm creating a GUI and I need to keep always visible the label that I put on the bottom, even if I shrink the window. ='m a begineer user. I searched for some solution, but they never worked.
Can you help me please?

This is the code I working on:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
#root.minsize(120,120)

frame1=ttk.LabelFrame(root, text = 'Menu Bar', height=100)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(root)
frame3 = ttk.Frame(root)

frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()
frame3.pack()

button1=ttk.Button(frame1, text = 'Button 1')
button2=ttk.Button(frame1, text = ' Button 2')
button3=ttk.Button(frame2, text = 'Button 3')
Label1 = ttk.Label(root, text = "Bottom text: do not hide")

button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack()
Label1.pack(side= BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen vs what actually happened? Can we have a comparison screenshot maybe

Comment: What is the purpose of `frame3`? Were you intending to put the label in it, or did you really intend for the label to be in the root window?

Answer (score 0):

When the window is too small to fit all of the widgets in their requested size, it starts shrinking widgets in their packing order. That means that the last widget to get packed is the first to get shrink.

The simple solution is to rearrange the order in which things are packed. For example:

```
Label1.pack(side= BOTTOM)
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()
frame3.pack()
button1.pack(side=LEFT)
button2.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.pack()
```